# No notifications from characteristicvaluechanged in web bluetooth

Tags: javascript, web, bluetooth

I have a LM068 BLE serial adapter which I'm trying to communicate with from a web app. I have tested it from the nRF Connect app on Android, where the communication works fine.

The characteristic has the properties "notify" and "writeWithoutResponse".

When calling `characteristic.startNotifications()` I get an error "GATT Error: invalid attribute length.".

Calling `characteristic.writeValue()` successfully sends the data, and I can see the incoming data in my serial monitor. When sending data from the serial terminal, the characteristicvaluechanged event never fires. Notifications works from the nRF Connect app.

This is part of my current code:

```js
const characteristic = await service.getCharacteristic(characteristicName)

try {
  await characteristic.startNotifications()
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e.message)
  // GATT Error: invalid attribute length.
}

const encoder = new TextEncoder('utf-8')
characteristic.writeValue(encoder.encode('test')) // Works

characteristic.addEventListener('characteristicvaluechanged', handleValueChanged) // Never gets called
```

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that the way I was testing the web app was the issue. I didn't have a BLE dongle for my workstation, so I was using my phone to access my development server. Of course web bluetooth needs to be either run on localhost or from https, so I simply ran the development server on https and accessed it on the network from my phone (like https://192.168.0.x). I proceeded even though chrome deemed it unsafe, but apparently only part of web bluetooth works this way.

Pairing and writeWithoutResponse works with an unsigned certificate. Notifications does not.

I'm leaving this here in case anyone else makes the same mistake.